# Cut continuous data by outliers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, outliers

For example I have DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'b': [2, 2, 4, 3, 1000, 2000, 1, 500, 3]})
```

[image]

I need to cut by outliers and get these intervals: 1-4, 5-6, 7, 8, 9.

Cutting with pd.cut and pd.qcut does not give these results

Comment: using the formula, 500 and 1000 are not outliers

Comment: You removed the formula, but what is the logic? I can come up with many ways to get the desired result **for this dataset**, but will it make sense in a general case?

Comment: ok, outliers are all rows where b is more than 100

Comment: this question is not about outlier detection, it about cutting

Comment: It looks like you want a group, not really a cut (that is grouping based on numerical bins, not consecutive items with a given property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them by consecutive values depending on the above/below mask:

```
m = df['b'].gt(100)
df['group'] = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
```

output:

```
   a     b  group
0  1     2      1
1  2     2      1
2  3     4      1
3  4     3      1
4  5  1000      2
5  6  2000      2
6  7     1      3
7  8   500      4
8  9     3      5
```